# How do you turn off clean URLs in the database?

Tags: database, 8, uri

How do I turn off clean URLs in Drupal 8 from the database? What table do I look in and what variable do I have to change?

Comment: Why can't you use Drush/Drupal Console? It will be more reliable

Comment: @Clive - Because I am a noob and still learning how to do all this stuff

Comment: I am not 100% sure if all parts that tie into the routing system still work with clean URLs disabled.  I do remember banging my head against the wall with some of this code when I was working all of the issues leading up to removing `l()` and `url()`, but I don't recall where all of it landed.

Answer (score 3):

In drupal 8 this setting has been removed:

['clean_url' configuration setting removed; clean URLs are autodetected each request](https://www.drupal.org/node/1659580)

I checked the database, there is really no setting with this name.

Comment: Thanks for the link, when I type index.php I can at least see my pages, now I just need to figure out how to fix this on my server...

Comment: Is it Apache or Nginx @ShemSeger (or something else)?

Comment: @Clive My web server is running Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Ubuntu is your OS - a web server is a bit of software that runs on top of that. It's likely to be Apache or Nginx; more likely Apache if you're unsure. But find that out first, it's important. There's probably a small config change to make there and everything'll work

Comment: @Clive I've never used Nginx, I installed the LAMP package so I'm using Apache. I've enable rewrite, added all sorts of stuff to my default-ssl.conf, done pretty much everything I can find documentation on, but my problem started when I updated to Drupal 8.0.2 yesterday, so there isn't a whole lot of up to date documentation.

Comment: A couple of things to try then: 1. When you update the root .htaccess is overwritten - did you by chance have changes in there which made the site work previously with your web server? Worth checking version control/a backup to make sure. 2. Make sure `AllowOverride All` is somewhere in the web root directory in your vhost for the site - if you're having trouble getting all URLs rewritten it's possible .htaccess isn't being processed. 3. Make sure the web server user has read access for .htaccess. Strange things can happen when you update depending on method used

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/34031/discussion-between-shemseger-and-clive).